# When $A$ is not a closed set, there exists an element $c\in X\setminus A$ and a sequence ${x_n}$ in A for all $n\ge1$ where $x_n$ converges to $c$

Tags: general-topology

I am told to start with the negation of Open set.  Let $V= X\setminus A$.  I have that $V$ is not Open if for all $r>0$, There exists $a \in V$ such that the open ball $B(a,r)$ is not a subset of $V$.

Is that the correct negation of open set?

Comment: How your question title relates to the content of the question is a little bit ambiguous since you don't mention sequences anywhere. That being said, a set $A$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ is open if, for every $x\in A$, there exists a positive number $r>0$ such that $\{y\in X \mid d(x,y)<r\}\subset A$. Negating this, a set $A\subset (X,d)$ is not open if there exists $x\in A$ such that for every $r>0$, the set $\{y\in X \mid d(x,y)<r\}$ is not contained by $A$.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must switch $\forall r>0$ and $\exists a\in V$.

$V$ is an open set iff $V$ is an open neighbourhood of any of its points, or equivalently for all $a\in V$, there exists $r>0$ such that the open ball $B(a,r)$ is included in $V$ (if we are in a metric space).

The negation of this is that there exists $a\in V$ such that for all $r>0$, the open ball $B(a,r)$ is not contained in $V$.

So if $A$ is not a closed set, then $X\backslash A$ is not open so there exists $c\in X\backslash A$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N^*$, the open ball $B(a,\frac1n)$ is not contained in $X\backslash A$. Let $n\in\mathbb N^*$. Since $B(a,\frac1n)$ is not contained in $X\backslash A$, there exists $x_n\in B(a,\frac1n)$ such that $x_n\notin X\backslash A$, or equivalently $d(x_n,a)<\frac1n$ and $x_n\in A$. Then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$ is a sequence in $A$ which converges to $a$.